# LeafLetJS TimeDimension: accumulate the features on the map

Tags: leaflet, wms

I have configured a leaflet timedimension layer according the code bellow. The point features are displayed only when the player receives the feature time and when the time is over the features are removed. How can I accumulate the features over the map after the player goes through the time? I mean, the features will be displayed as the player goes on and they are kept over the map. Is there any timedimension option for that?

```
var timeDimension = new L.TimeDimension({
    timeInterval: "2020-04-29/2020-04-30",
    period: "PT5M"
});

var fire_event = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(fire);
```

Comment: I suppose format returned from WMS service is GeoJSON. Do you have some URL of such a service that could be tested?

Comment: @Ian Turton. Great to have you here. Loading a GeoJSON works fine [var geojson = L.timeDimension.layer.geoJson(timeSeriesLayer)]. When you add timedimension features from a GeoJSON, they are kept on the map, even when the feature's time is over. However if you add a WMS PostGIS layer (var fire_evento = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(fire);), the features just flashes on the map and disappears.  Unfortunately I do not have a public server to share the URL. I am working with the fire data available in https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/mapserver/wfs-info/.

Comment: Layers on the mentioned site are available only in bitmap format. It's impossible for bitmaps to stay on the map when the next one in time series comes.